# AngularJS ui.calendar next and prev events

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way of handling the next month and prev month events in a ui.calendar directive?

This is my config:

```
vm.config = _.assign({
        height: 450,
        editable: true,
        header: {
          left: '',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventClick: vm.eventRender,
        eventRender: vm.eventRender
    }, uiCalendarConfig);
```

And this is my directive:

```
<div ui-calendar="vm.config" ng-model="vm.eventSources"></div>
```

For now, I would really like to log to the console the current month and year when the user click the > or < buttons in the header of my calendar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on event render you receive view object, this object  have 2 properties, intervalStart, intervalEnd,you can use to extract the data you want. The eventRender method is invoked every time you click one of the buttons